# Typescript accessing a class property by bracket notation

Tags: typescript

[Playground Link for issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CUIHc4CWAtmEsEcAHYyZbALQAmAPGjFAZQOYA0cKlAJ4A+OAG8AUHDhcOjAIJRgKAFz8hAbimFKjUGsoBXIgCNgULdID6BNAAlleqGpMQIZAZcTAkSNGoFBAG0AXS8YCDADYzMLCW0GSjYoQwQIqAAKWQIFJVV1QT5OPRBo03MASnFtaRgAC1sAOmzc5TgAXhk5RWUvWoa0RuLQDp0Svrh6ppt7R3NRgDMUP2AJqcGEHz9R0LWBxoiwUYAGLwBfKQkLiQXDSjSCCEp+RkYcXAyUGHZ-AqrJaSJNhwKB4UaUYD4d4ZADkLR6KBhfGOFS8C2gcAyZHgAGtgIIdPxvlA0P8aognsCAG7LQzAUZfH5BPGCMLk0G4Zn4kKjGlIOnnK5AA)

I'm trying to understand why typescript is complaining about me trying to access a class property through via bracket notation. I have my class below:

```
export class Row implements Record<string, any> {

  gridArea: GridArea;
  index: number;
  _isHeader: boolean;
  _isSelectable: boolean;
  cells: Cell[];
  top: number;
  ...

}
```

And later on I am creating an instance of this class and attempting to set properties on it based on an object of key value pairs:

```
addRow(attrs: any) {
  const row = new Row(this.mainGridArea, this.rows.length);
  for (let key in attrs) {
    const value = attrs[key];
    row[key] = value;
  }
  ...
}
```

but the line:

```
row[key] = value;
```

is failing to compile with the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Row'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Row'.

I've not worked with Records before, but had come to the conclusion to use it based on other stackoverflow questions/answers, however I'm still running into issues. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I could swear I've seen this problem before (different specifics of course)l. I think the answer was that TypeScript doesn't support `class X implements Record<x, y>`.

Comment: Is `Row` designed to be free-form, or does it have specific keys (in other words, why are you trying to implement `Record`)?

Comment: @crashmstr it has specific keys as far as I know, I was implementing `Record` as I thought it was needed to allow the idea that properties are string-based. Removing that implementation from the class does nothing to resolve the error however

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so it constitutes a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WK8aow) to demonstrate your issue.  It's *possible* this will go away if you make `Row` have an index signature, but whether that's the right thing to do or not depends on the use case, and whether it works depends on the reproducible example.

Comment: @jcalz I've added a link to the top of the post

Comment: const row:any = new Row('gridArea', 0); if we declare row as any  then no error

Comment: So does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8nZN) work for you then?

Comment: yes i cheked in  typescript playground

Comment: (clarifying prior comment) @AlexR does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8nZN) meet your needs?

Comment: @jcalz thanks that's resolved the errors. I don't suppose you know why it is that I need to set that property to allow bracket notation to work? I don't need to have the class implement Record, but removing it doesn't stop the error unless I keep your fix as well

Comment: The `implements Record<string, any>` doesn't really do much one way or the other.  But is the intent that you can safely just copy any old property to any old key?  If so, then adding an index signature to that effect is reasonable.  If not, then you really don't want `attrs` to be `any` and instead it needs to be something like `Row` itself, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8pYN) maybe.  If your [mcve] had some criteria for success/failure other than "stop compiler errors" I might be more confident in that solution.  What is the use case here?